# Better way to programmatically Lock/Disable multiple UI controls on Ribbon bar

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, ribbon

I have been wondering, what would be the better way to implement Locking/Disabling a bunch of Ribbon UI controls by just a click?

Currently, my approach is kinda simple and basic:

```
private void tbtnLock_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
       {
           if (tbtnLock.Checked)
           {
               control1.Enabled = false;
               control2.Enabled = false;
               control3.Enabled = false;
               //...
               //controlN.Enabled = false;
           }
           else
           {
               control1.Enabled = true;
               control2.Enabled = true;
               control3.Enabled = true;
               //...
               //controlN.Enabled = true;
           }
       }
```

I think it's okay if we only have just a few controls but once we add more and more controls onto the Ribbon bar, I don't think it'd be a good coding practice to do things like above.

Is there any cleaner and neater approach to this? Am I able to get the collection of all the controls on the Ribbon bar? Hopefully someone can give me some pointers here? Thanks very much.

EDIT:

Revised code below:

```
private void tbtnLock_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
        {
            toggleUILockState();
        }
private void toggleUILockState()
        {
            if (group1.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (RibbonControl c in group1.Items)
                {
                    if (c.Name != "tbtnLock")
                    {
                        c.Enabled = !tbtnLock.Checked;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I think it looks a lot better than the previous version. Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: What happens when you just disable the ribbon bar itself?

Comment: But I need to keep the lock button available.

Comment: Keep in mind you will not loop through the `RibbonControl`s included inside `RibbonBox`es

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well certainly the first step to improve the code would be to remove the if statement and assigned the enabled state of the control directly with the checked state of the tbtnLock control like...

```
control1.Enabled = !tbtnLock.Checked;
control2.Enabled = !tbtnLock.Checked;
```

that would cut your code if half straight away. You may want to assign that to a bool first incase you want to do additional processing on it later (maybe some other object helps determining lock state for example)

```
bool isEnabled = !tbtnLock.Checked;

control1.Enabled = isEnabled;
control2.Enabled = isEnabled;
```

Further than that I would need to know what "ribbon" control you are using. Do you have a link?

But as you have hinted, I would want to look at trying to find a colleciton of controls, loop through them, check if the control is not the tbtnLock control and disable/enable as needed.

Also, I would recommend move all this code to a function outside of the event handle, in case you need to call this method from other code. Something like...

```
private void tbtnLock_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
   UpdateRibbonState();
}

private void UpdateRibbonState(){
   //Code goes here
}
```

**EDIT**: Making assumtion that a "group" (as described in comments) has a collection of controls...

```
foreach(Control c in group.Controls)
{
   if(c.Name != "tbtnLock")
   {
      c.Enabled = !tbtnLock.Checked;
   }
}
```

I am not familiar with any built-in .Net ribbon controls and as there is no link to a 3rd party set) I am making a best guess at the properties available for a "group"

Comment: thanks for explaining in detail. really appreciated. the controls I am using are just ribbon buttons, togglebuttons. there may will be some other types of controls added onto the ribbon in the future. Also I have pretty much grouped these buttons in 1 group (lock button is in the same group too).

Comment: @woodykiddy: see my edit, not sure it will run as it stands but hopefully will point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could put all your UI controls into one list and then iterate it to enable/disable them all at once. Something like (untested/pseudocode):

```
List<RibbonBase> listMyControls = new List<RibbonBase>()
{
  control1, control2, control3, ... , controlN
};

foreach (var control in listMyControls)
{
  control.Enabled = !tbtnLock.Checked;
}
```

Comment: hmm, very enlightening. But is there going to be any different if I choose ArrayList over List?

Comment: Unless you're stuck in .NET 1.0 or something, I would never ever use ArrayList. List's have more features, they maintain type and they're very easy to work with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code to extend this to an entire tab.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Enable or Disable all buttons in all groups of the RibbonTab to match toggleButtonActive
    /// toggleButtonActive remains enabled
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="enabled"></param>
    private void SetUILockState(bool enabled)
    {
        foreach (RibbonGroup group in myRibbonTab.Groups)
        {
            if (group.Items != null)
            {
                foreach (RibbonControl c in group.Items)
                {
                    if (c.Name != "toggleButtonActive")
                    {
                        c.Enabled = enabled;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        // TODO handle right click menus as well
    }
```

Comment: I have two guesses on the answer above: 1) For some RibbonControls you have to do more/other than set "Enabled = false". E.g. for a SplitButton you have to set "splitButton.ButtonEnabled = false" 2) The Disable-Function should be recursive because you can have child controls e.g. in a RibbonMenu-Control.

Comment: If a menu is disabled, does it really matter if its children are not? I did not run into the split button case, but that seems like an unfortunate interface deviation if it is true.

Comment: I unfortunately did (run into the SplitButton case :-) 
It may be better to disable all children of a RibbonMenu because every RibbonButton can be put to the Quick Access Toolbar for example - or may be used on other places by user ribbon customizations.